# Mongodb change Stream 4.0

Tags: mongodb

I have 15 sub-documents in array field abc

While updating element (pqr) single sub-document in array field

Then MongoDB changestraem will return the specific element with position {"abc.0.pqr":"updatedvalue"} in ChangeStream.UpdateDescription.UpdatedFields

and when we update element "pqr" in all sub-document the changeStream returning all 15 document with all elements

How we can handle these scenarios as the output of ChangeStream.UpdateDescription.UpdatedFields is totally different in both case.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by `handle` these scenarios? They're different  operations after all, could you describe what you're trying to do and the challenge that you faced ?

Comment: If I want to PUSH the ChangeStream.UpdateDescription.UpdatedFields to some MQ or some other DB I need uniform input to push.Single update can be manage from the code side but in case of multiple update difficult check which field exactly updated

Comment: Could you post an example change stream output from both operations ?